# Копирование и перемещение

Tags: c++

Когда лучше использовать копирование, а когда перемещение?
(Когда большие объекты лучшие копировать(даже если дальше их не используем)?)

Всегда ли перемещение эффективнее копирования?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Когда лучше использовать копирование, а когда перемещение?

- когда перемещение будет дешевле
- когда объект не предусматривает копирования (например, файловый дескриптор)

> (Когда большие объекты лучшие копировать(даже если дальше их не используем)?)

- когда у нас хороший компилятор и он может применить rvo/nrvo (и подобное). В этом случае по факту не будет копирования.
- с копированием иногда легче сделать "иммутабельность" - каждый поток владеет своей копией объекта - это бывает лучше, чем разделять объект с помощью объектов синхронизации (мютекстов)

> Всегда ли перемещение эффективнее копирования?

В теории оно вроде так. Но на практике может быть все наоборот. Так как программист сам пишет конструкторы/операторы копирования/перемещения, то он может написать все, что угодно - например, добавить `sleep(1000000)` в оператор перемещения.

Также не стоит забывать, что многие вопросы производительности хорошо решает компилятор, если ему не мешать. Если раньше возврат объекта с функции грозил до двух копирований, и деструктором, то сейчас (с++17) это просто один конструктор, а иногда компилятор даже и его выбросит.

Comment: Вообще возврат объектов из функций это зло и синтаксический сахар. По хорошему все функции должны быть void, а объекты извольте передавать через параметры. И тут уж программист сам решает, сразу ли укладывать данные по полям предоставленного ему указателя или сначала сформировать внутри функции свою копию объекта, а потом скопировать его целиком в предоставленный указатель. И не надо никаких конструкторов перемещений, незачем плодить лишние сущности.

Comment: Функции, которые возвращают void, называются процедуры, но тут возникает сразу целый спектр новых проблем. Так что лучше использовать функции